# Regex return value based on condition

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

I have two possible inputs that I need to parse with regex:

> 192.168.1.1:80 [172.16.1.1:8080]

or

> 192.168.1.1:80 [172.16.1.1]

If the :8080 is present I want to return 8080 but if not I want to return 80.

Is this possible?

Thanks

Comment: what have you tried..which language are you using..are those two input's in a single string or are they separate..

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with positive lookbehind and negative lookahead..

```
(?<=:)\d+(?!.*:\d+)
```

---

Altenatively you can use

```
 .*:(\d+)
```

Group 1 captures what you want

Comment: Your first statement comes up as invalid.  That is most likely a problem with the software I am using.  Your second suggestion works however, I only posted a portion of the input.  There would be another instance of an ip:port.  Sorry my bad.  So the "real" input would like this:192.168.1.1:80 [172.16.1.1:8080] -> 10.100.100.1:443

Comment: BTW - I found a way to use two regex statement in the software that I am using so this question is moot.  However, I am still interested to know if this type of statement is possible